# Error processing element GELF ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND

Tags: logging, log4j2, graylog2, gelf

I am getting the following error in my log4j2.xml file:

```
Error processing element GELF ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
```

At first I thought it was because I was referencing an invalid appender, but I still have the error after commenting it out.

Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" packages="org.graylog2.log4j2">

<Appenders>
    <GELF   name="gelfAppender" 
            server="org.graylog2.log.GelfAppender" 
            port="12201"
            hostName="some.host" 
            facility="GELF-JAVA"
            extractStacktrace="true"
            addExtendedInformation="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${some_pattern}"/>
         <!-- Additional fields -->
        <KeyValuePair key="someKey" value="someVal"/>
    </GELF>
</Appenders>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out I was missing a couple of dependencies; no more error! :D

Comment: which dependecies did you miss? i have same problem.

Comment: What were the dependencies you were missing?

Comment: Sorry I dont remember and don't have the project anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was missing this dependency in the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graylog2.log4j2</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j2-gelf</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

[This](https://programmer.help/blogs/springboot-uses-graylog-log-collection.html) article helped me a lot.